# Allow someone else to connect to my XAMPP mysql

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

Good day,

I am making a discord bot that will require MySQL access. I have used XAMPP in the past for other projects, but now that I am working with someone else, I need to allow them to also access my XAMPP MySQL database. I have tried googling solutions, as well as looking up a lot of other stuff for this, but everything just redirects back to localhost/virtualhost stuff.

I have my own DNS that I would like the person to connect to, so [example](http://www.mywebsite.com/phpmyadmin).

I am trying to run this entire thing off my own server, this way I do not have to worry about data limitations or worry about if the project goes inactive for a while that everything will be wiped (remotemysql.com)

Only kind of success I have had so far is allowing another computer on my LAN to connect through my IPv4 address

I have the ports, 3306, 80, and 443 all open as well as allowed through my firewall. I have also tried temp disabling my firewall to test to see if this was the issue, but it wasnt

Comment: So, no one can reach you from the external, you're reachable only from your Lan? Is this right? Do you have a static IP? Have you checked your Router settings?

Comment: I reorganised the shape of post

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you want to that just for testing, if it is, maybe [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) could work for you.

It creates tunnels to localhost, but it has no custom domains on the free plan though.

Comment: Though this does work, however this is only 8 hours per use with the free plan. Is there a way to do this with just xampp or maybe even nodejs that will allow me to keep this online for as long as my computer is online? Looking to try and get this to as close as free as possible

Comment: I never tried other services to point out one but there is alternatives searching for 'localhost tunnelling' for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Use ngrok. Alternatively if you want it to be free in terms of use, you can setup your own ngrok like server using expose. Here is the link https://github.com/beyondcode/expose